# How to Implement OCR in Android application?

Tags: android, ocr

Boss has asked us to think of a way to scan employee card numbers and save them in our application, I'm not sure what the best way to tackle this issue? (I'm new)

Ideally it should automatically recognize the numbers without requiring the user to save the picture in his drive

Are there any non-propretial libraries that are easy to implement or is the answer something else entirely?

I've looked tesseract but I'm not sure if its free to use and it doesn't seem like it will work with android

Comment: Just be aware that Google has a [codelabs site](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/) showing off various features. The [Recognize Text and Facial Features](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android#0) may be one to look at. Be aware that there are on-device (generally free) and cloud based (API pricing) solutions.